# Normalizing samples to 0 mean and 1 variance , in online machine learning algorithms

Tags: math, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I am currently working on an online machine learning algorithm, where I need to make sure each feature in the input vector has a 0 mean and 1 variance across the samples.
I think its trivial how to do this when you have all the samples beforehand, but this isn't the case in online learning.
Does anybody know how to normalize a new given vector in such a way so that each feature across the previous samples (+ the new one) has 0 mean and 1 variance?
Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap the first few hundred samples, estimate the mean and variance and do Gaussian normalization to mean 0 and variance 1, and normalize any future vector to this. No ML Algo is very strict about normalization to 0,1 and this should suffice.

For a strictly online problem where you learn from first defect onwards, I am not sure how to do it, unless you have some ideas of the range of the variables like max value of a pixel in grey scale image etc. Renormalizing and re-training after say every x defects are collected would prove way too costly.